# solaris + match the network device name according to IP address

Tags: solaris, shell-scripting

how to find the device name as ( e1000g2 , e1000g3 , etc ) according to his IP address on Solaris machine

for example

```
   ifconfig -a | grep 10.106.134.133

       inet 10.106.134.133 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.106.134.255
```

ifconfig with grep command view only the line with the IP address , and the device name appears before the IP address

so my target is to match the device name according to the IP address on Solaris machine , and then insert the device name in to parameter ( ksh )

please advice?

full example: from ifconfig -a ( I get the IP and device name , what I need is to find the device name according to IP address , and insert the device name in to parameter )

```
 e1000g2: flags=201000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,CoS> mtu 1500            inet 10.106.134.133 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.106.134.255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a horrible hack but for now

```
#!/bin/ksh
ipaddr=$1
ifconfig -a | nawk '/'"$ipaddr"'/ { printf "%s",prev;print };{prev=$0}' | awk '{print $1,$8}'
```

and

```
usage scriptname ip.add.re.ss
```

Comment: I get error - awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: awk 'print $1,$8}' should be: awk 'print {$1,$8}'

Comment: ifconfig -a | nawk '/'"$ipaddr"'/ { printf "%s",prev;print };{prev=$0}' | awk 'print {$1,$8}' 
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Should be {print $1,$8} - fixed